# How to get output of a command only when it is a single line of text?

Tags: batch-file, variables

In a batch file, I am using the following to get the ouput of a command :

```
for /f %%i in ('command') do set output=%%i
```

`command` is supposed to output a single line of text, and I get the expected output in `%output%` in such a case.

However, `command` sometimes outputs several lines of text, which represents an error. In such a situation, I get the last one in `%output%` and I don't know that `command` did output more than a single line.

How to check when `command` outputs more than one single line of text ?

Note: I don't need to know what the outputs are when there are several lines; I only need to known that more than a single line was output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set "output="
for /f %%i in ('command') do if defined output (
echo "error"
) else (
set output=%%i
)
```

Using the fact that `if defined` interprets the run-time status of the target variable

Answer (score 0):

…or maybe

```cmd
for /f %%i in ('command 2^>nul') do set output=%%i
```

*it's hard to say when we don't know what command or error output is*

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of `2^>nul` ? When trying, it's interpreted as a command parameter...

Comment: Because your command and output are a secret, it's hard to give you a definitive answer. If you want help you have to provide sufficient information to get the appropriate solution.

Comment: The normal syntax is `command 2>nul`; if parsed by a `for /F` loop you need to escape the redirection operator `>`, because otherwise it would be detected for the entire `for /F` command line. Anyway, this is completely useless with respect to `output`, because `for /F` does not capture error text anyway, which is surpressed by `2>nul`...

Comment: @aschipfl, it's not 'completely useless' at all because the OP has stated that they don't need to know what the error outputs are, meaning that they dont need it. That means that the variable %output% should only exist if there were no errors which is easily checkable.

Comment: I said "useless with respect to `output`", which is what the OP is interested in; it is of course not useless in general...

Comment: @Compo @aschipfl : `command` does not output anything to `stderr`; what I wrote is that when it outputs several lines (to `stdout`), it is considered as an error : _"sometimes outputs several lines of text, which represents an error"_

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.exe /k "for /f %%i in ('command') do set output=%%i" > C:/Users/%username%/Desktop/Output.txt
```